# Bootstrap hide and show div based on sidebar menu item clicked

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and still trying to familiarize myself with the available classes that I can use. So, I tried to build a sidebar but I can't get it to show only the target `div` of the menu item clicked on the sidebar.

In other words, one `div` at a time and not stack of `div`s.

To better illustrate, here's a screenshot.

[image]

It doesn't replace the current `div`, instead it just simply shows the `div` then hides it on `button` click. This ends up on displaying or hiding one or both of the `div`s everytime I click on a menu item on the sidebar

**dashboard.xhtml**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#customer-div" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#orders-div" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Orders</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                        <li><a href="">Frames</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Posters</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Users</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>



                <!-- CUSTOMER -->
                <div id="customer-div" class="well col-xs-8 collapse">
                    <h1>CUSTOMER</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- END OF CUSTOMER DIV -->

                <!-- ORDERS -->
                <div id="orders-div" class="well col-xs-8 collapse">
                    <h1>ORDERS</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- END OF ORDERS DIV -->

            </div>
        </div>
```

I want one `div` to replace the current `div` on it's container.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap `nav-tabs` to achieve this. 
Here is the example code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <h2>Dynamic Pills</h2>
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <h3>HOME</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Menu 1</h3>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Menu 2</h3>
          <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Menu 3</h3>
          <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

working jsfiddle: [bootstrap tabs stacked](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav)

reference: [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav)

Answer (score 1):

What Rajesh suggested is a good alternative.

But if you wanted to achieve your goal while still keeping using sidebar, you can do so by introducing some Javascript code. Example:

```js
function showCustomers() {
    $('#orders-div').hide();
    $('#customer-div').show();
  }

  function showOrders() {
    $('#customer-div').hide();
    $('#orders-div').show();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#customer-div" class="btn btn-default" onclick="showCustomers()">Customers</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#orders-div" class="btn btn-default" onclick="showOrders()">Orders</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="">Frames</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Posters</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Users</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>



    <!-- CUSTOMER -->
    <div id="customer-div" class="well col-xs-8 collapse">
      <h1>CUSTOMER</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF CUSTOMER DIV -->

    <!-- ORDERS -->
    <div id="orders-div" class="well col-xs-8 collapse">
      <h1>ORDERS</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF ORDERS DIV -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Bootstrap Accordion](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#accordion-example)

Just change your codes into these...

**Buttons**

```
<li><a href="#customer-div" class="btn btn-default" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Customers</a></li>
<li><a href="#orders-div" class="btn btn-default" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Orders</a></li>
```

**Customer and Order divs**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <!-- CUSTOMER -->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="customer-div" class="panel-collapse collapse in well col-xs-8">
       <h1>CUSTOMER</h1>
     </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END OF CUSTOMER DIV -->

  <!-- ORDERS -->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="orders-div" class="panel-collapse collapse well col-xs-8">
      <h1>ORDERS</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END OF ORDERS DIV -->
</div>
```